# MongoDB $geoIntersects does not work with polygons that contain negative vertices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I have stored polygons in the database that cross over the x and y axes and I want to search for polygons that contain a given point. To do so, I am using the $geoIntersects operator to specify a point, however, MongoDB does not return any polygons when they cross over an axis. Are there any small changes I can make to my query or schema that will allow for this?

The query:

```
{
    polygon: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [long, lat]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The object in the database:

```
polygon: {

        type: 'Polygon',

        name: 'Name',

        coordinates: [[
            [-180, -90],
            [-180, 90],
            [180, 90],
            [180, -90],
            [-180, -90]
        ]]

    }
```