# $geoIntersects does not work with polygons that contain negative vertices - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geojson, geo

I have stored polygons in a MongoDB database that cross over the X and Y axes and I want to search for polygons that contain a given point. To do so, I am using the $geoIntersects operator to specify a point, however, MongoDB does not return any polygons when they cross over an axis.

One of the objects in the collection:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59caabf5f3c18e787b5df921"), 
"polygons" : {
    "type" : "Polygon", 
    "coordinates" : [
        [
            [
                -100.31350135803223, 
                25.7219723533502
            ], 
            [
                -100.31290054321289, 
                25.72386681990707
            ], 
            [
                -100.31036853790283, 
                25.72332554682729
            ], 
            [
                -100.31116247177124, 
                25.721102435127573
            ]
        ]
    ]
  }
}
```

These coordinates correspond to a polygon surrounding [this location](https://www.google.com.mx/maps/place/University+Stadium/@25.7226325,-100.3141836,17.12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x86629453362b628f:0x4758ce0b56be25e7!8m2!3d25.7225198!4d-100.3120225?hl=en), now, I'm querying to see if the stadium itself is inside the polygon (which it obviously is), like this:

```
db.testzones.find({
     polygons:{
       $geoIntersects:{
              $geometry:{ 
                 "type" : "Point", 
                 "coordinates" :   [-100.312060, 25.722381] 
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

But I'm not getting anything, however if I try with the exact data of [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578363/mongodb-check-if-point-is-in-polygon) accepted answer I do get a result, notice the absence of negative coordinates, this is what leads me to believe that those are what cause the problem.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392782/mongodb-geointersects-does-not-work-with-polygons-that-contain-negative-vertice) from last year (the problem is so similar to mine that I practically copied the title and the first paragraph) however it got no answer. Am I doing something wrong here? Or how could I go about solving this? I appreciate any help, I'm completely lost right now!